# const_cast with two levels pointers

Tags: c++, casting, const-cast

I want to do this conversion using C++ format, it works on the C way. but it fails when I try on C++ format.

It works!

```
void req_password(const void *data, size_t datalen)
{
    char *password_old = ((char **) data)[0];
    char *password_new = ((char **) data)[1];
    ...
}
```

It fails

```
void req_password(const void *data, size_t datalen)
{
    char *password_old = (const_cast<char **>(data))[0];
    char *password_old = (const_cast<char **>(data))[1];
    ...
}
```

error:

```
error: invalid const_cast from type 'const void*' to type 'char**'
```

So my doubt is, how could I do this conversion using the C++ way?

PS: This code is part from a API, I can't control the the input of data.

Comment: This is the format of the input that I receive, I cant change the format of the input parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that.

Comment: You need to first `const_cast` away the `const`ness, and then `reinterpret_cast` to `char **`. But this is some of the ugliest code I've seen on SO for a while.

Comment: Because of the rules of Google guide style.

Comment: Looks like you have a terrible API to work with, so I suppose it makes sense that you go about following a terrible style guide as well.

Comment: @Praetorian: You don't need to cast away any `const`ness at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Probably not (you already got +1 from me for pointing that out), I didn't put much effort into trying to figure out the intent before commenting. Shame on me :)

Comment: The API is from Android low level to work with Radio Layer Interface.

Comment: @Alex are you really going to modify those strings?

Comment: No, it can be constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't.**

If you are being given immutable data, then you are being given immutable data and that is the end of it!

First, here's what I suggest for maximum safety. Coercing `data` into its real type is a little tricky, alas:

```
void req_password(const void* data, size_t datalen)
{
    const char* password_old = (reinterpret_cast<const char* const*>(data)[0]);
    const char* password_new = (reinterpret_cast<const char* const*>(data)[1]);
    // ...
}
```

(I've actually *added* some `const`ness in the above, as it seems to be the intent of having `const void*` in the first place.)

But, if you *really* want the strings to be mutable, then this is fine too:

```
void req_password(const void* data, size_t datalen)
{
    char* password_old = (reinterpret_cast<char* const*>(data)[0]);
    char* password_new = (reinterpret_cast<char* const*>(data)[1]);
    // ...
    // More obvious when you recall that `const void*` is actually `void const*`;
    // So:
    //   void  const*
    // becomes:
    //   char* const*
}
```

Notice how you don't even *need* `const_cast` here, because you're not modifying the thing that `data` points to: you are dereferencing it and getting its pointee.

Of course, ideally, `data` would point to a `const std::string` instance.

Comment: should it be `(reinterpret_cast<const char* const*>(data))[0]`?

Comment: @Alex: Either is fine.